# When I swich scenes in blender game my scene gets darker

Tags: game-engine, scene

If I run my game scene without the menu scene everything it's fine, but if I first run the menu scene of the game and then get in my game scene everything is darker and my lamps are different than the ones I set.

Comment: Dude post you file so we can have a look inside, so many things can be a cause of problem. http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Maybe the menu scene is not set to Blender game engine but to blender render or cycles. If so, the scene you are entering from out the menu scene that's set to blender render will be in blender render too, I thought. The same for cycles though.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure both scenes have the same settings (e.g. Shading Material Mode: MultiTexture/GLSL). The BGE will use the settings of the startup scene throughout the whole game.